# Hibernate: HQL Row Count Subquery issue

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to work with a subquery/sub-select in HQL (Hibernate) but it doesn't work and throws an error...

I wanna know if there is an equivalent in HQL to something like this: ("normal" SQL)

```
select count(Z) from (SELECT SUM(existencia), almacen, oficina, fila from re_tinventarioubicacion where inventorybranchto = 2 GROUP BY almacen, oficina, fila, estante, entrepano, casilla, precioetiqueta) as Z
```

I have tried to "translate" it from SQL to HQL, but it doesn't work... it throws this:

org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

Basically, I need to get the row count from the resulting subquery.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use native SQL queries with hibernate but you'll need a simple POJO to map the return value to (actually in this case you might try some of the built-in transformers or try setting a Projection, i'm not sure if it would work or not).

POJO return value:

```
public class MyCount {
    private Integer count;

    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }    

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Query:

```
Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("select count(*) from dual");
    .addScalar("count")
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyCount.class));

MyCount count = (MyCount) query.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up using native SQL, but not Projection nor Transformers. But I believe Transformers may be a partial solution, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant select something in HQL without query an entity.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's related to the fact that you can't place sub-selects in the **from** section of a HQL query, but only in the **select** and **where** sections (this would be the case of directly "translating" from SQL to HQL, in the example I put there).